# Stored procedure not working some syntax error

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am learning about stored procedures and wrote the following:

```
delimiter //

create procedure show_inv(in inv_num int)
    beign
    select * from items
    where items.invoice_num = inv_num;
    end
    //
    delimiter ;
```

This is a simple procedure where an invoice number inserted for lookup.

I am getting the following error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select * from items
where items.invoice_num = inv_num;
end' at line 3
```

The query itself runs fine but the stored procedure seems to have an error and I don't know where it is.

Comment: Is it `beign` instead of `begin`?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `;` and typo for `begin` after the end so the procedure would be as

```
delimiter //

create procedure show_inv(in inv_num int)
begin
select * from items
where items.invoice_num = inv_num;
end ; //
delimiter ;
```

Here is a test case, the select is from a different table but rest all is same

```
mysql> select * from student ;
+---------------+----------+
| studentnumber | name     |
+---------------+----------+
|            11 | AAAAAAAA |
|            17 | BBBBBBB  |
|             8 | CCCCCCC  |
+---------------+----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> delimiter //
mysql> create procedure show_inv(in inv_num int)
    -> begin
    -> select * from student where studentnumber = inv_num ;
    -> end ; //
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> delimiter ;
mysql> call show_inv(11);
+---------------+----------+
| studentnumber | name     |
+---------------+----------+
|            11 | AAAAAAAA |
+---------------+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: I don't think the `;` is supposed to be after `end`  though I will agree on the typo